# When I click links on my web app it takes me to the new page, scrolled down on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, google-chrome

In chrome, I click on the nav links on my page and it takes me to the intended path, but instead of being at the top of the page, it's offset depending on how much I was scrolled down on the page I clicked from.  I think it's a chrome issue/feature, since it doesn't happen in firefox.

I'd like to have the links just go to the top of the page like how firefox behaves.  My links don't have any anchors in them.

I'm testing with chrome Version 31.0.1650.63

Comment: You need to post code, otherwise there are millions of different things that could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by updating my turbolinks gem from '1.1.1' to '2.1' 
This issue was addressed in issue #66 'reset scroll position on page replacement'

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/66

Hope that resolves the issue for you.